# Manipulate html page selection using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to figure out how to surround the html elements I select with a div tag programmatically. Here's what the markup would look like

```
sdfsdf<div class="highlight">sdjfksdjf<strong>dsfkjdf</strong>dfd</div>sdfdsf
```

this is the selection

```
sdjfksdjf<strong>dsfkjdf</strong>dfd
```

Comment: How are you selecting the text?

Comment: im selecting html elements on the page

Comment: So **HOW** do you select the elements? Click and drag the mouse over them? What's the objective (applying a css to them etc.)? I'd suggest going with JQuery.

Comment: As @FabrícioMatté suggested, please provide more code (if you have any), and detail what you're trying to do. If you're just trying to style the selected text, you can do that easily without complicated javascript. The more descriptive you are, the more we can help.

Comment: I suggest using http://jquery.com/. If you need I can elaborate on this.

Comment: Im trying to create a basic highlighting function. I select by highlighting the elements using the mouse then click a button that executes the function.

Comment: I'm currently trying to make that here: http://shaquin.tk/experiments/hilite.html. At the moment, highlights can be made, but problems occur if the selection overlaps or goes out of one element and into the next.

Answer (score 0):

You may need a GetElementsByClassName which has been natively supported in modern browsers:

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#gettingelements

For example:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('highlight');
```

Comment: im inserting that programmatically